# Give me more than all that you have, you can do it! Say it with me!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme

> Perhaps you've heard of me, I am the first,
> Closest to winning, I am not the worst,
>
> You think I'm the brass, nearly top of my class.
> Chasing the ones before, a prize I long for.
>
> Conducive of rounds, I will keep you up,
> Beastly I'm bound, if three of me form up.
>
> Indicating completion, I exist,
> Circular and double too, I'm two twists,
>
> Relationally similar to another here,
> Find out what these lines mean, and you'll have nothing to fear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lines clue

> the positive integers in increasing order.

Perhaps you've heard of me, I am the first,

> $1$ is the first positive integer.

Closest to winning, I am not the worst,

> $2$nd is closest to first, and according to the phrase "first the worst, second the best," second is not the worst.

You think I'm the brass, nearly top of my class.

> $3$rd place receives a bronze medal; bronze and brass are both copper alloys.

Chasing the ones before, a prize I long for.

> $4$th place is often the first to receive no prize.

Conducive of rounds, I will keep you up,

> $5$ is the first digit that is rounded up.

Beastly I'm bound, if three of me form up.

> $6$ repeated three times is the Number of the Beast in the Bible.

Indicating completion, I exist,

> $7$ indicates completion in the Bible, such as in the seven days of the week.

Circular and double too, I'm two twists,

> $8$ consists of two circles or twists.

Relationally similar to another here,

> $9$ is a rotated version of $6$.

Find out what these lines mean, and you'll have nothing to fear.

> Taking the appropriate letter of each line yields the Latin motto *plus ultra* meaning "further beyond," explaining the significance of the title.

Comment: You're right so far, but this is not all. Read the last line again, these all point to something.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think anyone would get that so quickly, good job.

Comment: Nice! I was trying to fit the title...

Comment: My hunch from the title (and what I believe it's referencing) turned out to be correct...

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT: Partial answer only, per OP's comment]

These are

> the numbers 1 through 9

Perhaps you've heard of me, I am the first,

> #1: winner

Closest to winning, I am not the worst,

> #2: second place

You think I'm the brass, nearly top of my class.

> #3: Bronze medal

Chasing the ones before, a prize I long for.

> #4: not in the top 3

Conducive of rounds, I will keep you up,

> #5 The first number that you round "up". (thanx to CGreen!)

Beastly I'm bound, if three of me form up.

> #6 The number of the beast is 666 (thanx to humfuzzj)

Indicating completion, I exist,

> #7 The seventh seal [biblical number of completion, per humfuzz]

Circular and double too, I'm two twists,

> #8 is shaped as two circles

Relationally similar to another here,

> #9 is similar-looking to "6"

Comment: 666 : rot13(ahzore bs gur ornfg)

Comment: "Conducive of rounds, I will keep you up" makes sense when rot13(ebhaqvat n ahzore hc)

Comment: The comments are right, however, this is not the complete answer, though you are correct so far. The last line means that the riddle/puzzle is not yet over, which is why I gave it the enigmatic tag.

Comment: 7: rot13(ovoyvpny ahzore bs pbzcyrgvba, v rkvfg=tbq)

Comment: @humfuzz You are right about 7 too.

Answer (score 1):

These can be lines describing

> 5 vowels( a, e, i, o, u)

As,

Perhaps you've heard of me, I am the first,
Closest to winning, I am not the worst,

> This is A.

You think I'm the brass, nearly top of my class.
Chasing the ones before, a prize I long for.

> This is for E -  the most frequently used vowel among the 5 vowels and second letter (after S) in the alphabets.

Conducive of rounds, I will keep you up,
Beastly I'm bound, if three of me form up.

> This is I - kind of ego, that keeps one up.

Indicating completion, I exist,
Circular and double too, I'm two twists,

> This is O, indicates nothingness or completion, though not sure of - twice part!

Relationally similar to another here,
Find out what these lines mean, and you'll have nothing to fear.

> This is for U( for *YOU*), and it *may* relate to 3rd one I, in a way.

Comment: Not quite right, but interesting take on it.